# Getting com.sap.spark.vora.VoraConfigurationException with "discovery" parameter

Tags: hana, vora

I've got HDP 2.3.4 cluster on SLES 11 SP3 with 3 machines and installed Vora 1.2

Finally got Discovery service to work. I can verify it in http://myclustermachine:8500/ui/#/dc1/services. Also, Vora Thriftserver doesn't die.

So I can get through the line "*val vc = new SapSQLContext(sc)*" on the page 34 of the Vora Installation Guide. But when I try to create a table, I get the following:

```
com.sap.spark.vora.VoraConfigurationException: Following parameter(s) are invalid: discovery
        at com.sap.spark.vora.config.ParametersValidator$.checkSyntax(ParametersValidator.scala:280)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.config.ParametersValidator$.apply(ParametersValidator.scala:98)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.resolveDataSource(CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.run(CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
```

What may be wrong this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a line in spark-defaults.conf that I added for discovery parameter: "spark.vora.discovery xxxxxxx:8500"

After I removed it, the whole thing works.